# Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

I have a task that waits for a user to enter any key to die. I have that task scheduled twice a day. However if the window is still up it will not run the task again. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the scheduled task.  Go to the settings tab.  Check the drop down menu at the bottom which says "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies" to "Run a new instance in parallel".

I'm looking at Windows 7 at the moment, but the task scheduler is pretty similar.